Select records columns where a minimum date exists for pair of columns
I am having an sql view "data", which looks like the following:



CALMONTH
COSTCENTER
KONTONUMMER
FIELDNM003




202212
Alpha
123
10


202301
Alpha
123
20


202210
Alpha
223
50


202307
Beta
123
10



I want to keep only the combinations of "COSTCENTER" and "KONTONUMMER" which have one or more entrries having "CALMONTH" >= 202301. The desired output would be:



CALMONTH
COSTCENTER
KONTONUMMER
FIELDNM003




202212
Alpha
123
10


202301
Alpha
123
20


202307
Beta
123
10



Right now I am only able, to do it only for one column "COSTCENTER":
SELECT "t"."CALMONTH", "t"."COSTCENTER", "t"."KONTONUMMER", "t"."FIELDNM003"
FROM "data" AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT "COSTCENTER"
  FROM "data"
  GROUP BY "COSTCENTER"
  HAVING MAX("CALMONTH") > 202301
) AS s ON s.COSTCENTER = t.COSTCENTER


You should identify any COSTCENTER and Kontonummer pairs that have at least one entry where "CALMONTH" >= 202301. After finding these pairs, join them with your table to retrieve all corresponding rows :
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
inner join (
  select COSTCENTER, Kontonummer
  from mytable
  where CALMONTH >= 202301
  group by COSTCENTER, Kontonummer
) as s on s.COSTCENTER = t.COSTCENTER
       and s.Kontonummer = t.Kontonummer;

Demo here
If you are using mysql 8 or higher, This is an other way to do it using window function MAX() :
select CALMONTH, COSTCENTER, Kontonummer, FIELDNM003
from (
  select *, max(CALMONTH) over (partition by COSTCENTER, Kontonummer) as max_CALMONTH
  from mytable
) as s
where max_CALMONTH >= '202301'


A simple exists query should do it:
SELECT *
FROM data AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM data AS x
    WHERE costcenter = t.costcenter
    AND   kontonummer = t.kontonummer
    AND   calmonth >= 202301
)


You can use a simple IN clause because they work with multiple columns in MySQL:
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE
  (costcenter, kontonummer) IN
    (SELECT costcenter, kontonummer
     FROM mytable
     WHERE calmonth >= 202301);

The inner query fetches all pairs that satisfy your date condition, the outer one adds the other columns.
Sample here: db<>fiddle
